# I have to find the records which contain 6-A, 6-B, 6-C...6-Z. using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `TABLE_1` and column `test` which has records in characters like `'AKLJNAAAAAAAIOUHIO', 'PIOJPMBBBBBBBPIO', 'OJPOIDDDDDDDPQP'...`

I have to find the records which contains `6-A`, `6-B`, `6-C` ... `6-Z` using SQL.

How can I do that?

Comment: None of the data samples contain what you are searching for. Please add some sensible data and expected results.

Comment: @vonPryz by `6-A` i think he means 6 A's in a row: `AAAAAA`

Comment: @Tanner It is waste of everybody's time trying to *guess* what the question actually is.

Comment: I am having records which contains alphanumeric and repeated char and nums.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain more fully how the values you wish to find are formatted and how they relate to the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Clean, but the naive version* will most likely perform better.

```
with t(i) as (select 0 union all select i+1 from t where i<25)
select      *
from        TABLE_1 
where       exists (select null from t where test like '%' + replicate(char(ascii('A')+t.i),6) + '%')
```

*

```
select      *
from        TABLE_1 
where       test like '%AAAAAA%'
        or  test like '%BBBBBB%'
        or  test like '%CCCCCC%'
        ...
```

Comment: it will run in postsql.. i am having restricted SQL. using Aginity.